# What form would a "real solution" for the Schrödinger equation of a free particle take?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The usual solution taught in textbooks for free particles (or particles inside constant potentials) is the plane wave solution, $\psi = A \exp (i \vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}-i\omega t)$. However this is not a normalizable solution and therefore it should not represent physical states. Then, what form would a free particle actually take?

Comment: Wavepackets are [dispersive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Dispersive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the underlying Hilbert space of your system is $L^2(\mathbb R)$, then a generic state takes the form
$$\psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\mathrm dk \ A(k) e^{ikx}$$
for some square-integrable function $A$, which loosely defines how "much" of the non-normalizable state $e^{ikx}$ is present in $\psi$.  If $\psi$ is the initial state of your system, then the state at time $t$ is
$$\Psi_t(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \mathrm dk \ A(k) e^{ikx} e^{-i\hbar k^2 t/2m}$$

---

In a more general context, if your Hamiltonian has non-normalizable eigenstates $\phi_k(x)$ which satisfy
$$\int \mathrm dx \ \overline{\phi_k(x)} \phi_q(x) = \delta(k-q)$$
and have generalized eigenvalues $E_k$, then a generic state of the system can be written as
$$\psi(x) = \int \mathrm dk \ A(k) \phi_k(x)$$
and, if this state is allowed to evolve for a time $t$, we would have
$$\Psi_t(x) = \int \mathrm dk \ A(k) \phi_k(x) e^{-iE_k t/\hbar}$$
In the free particle case, we have that
$$\phi_k(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ikx} \qquad E_k = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}$$

In the most general case, the spectrum of the Hamiltonian will have a discrete part $\sigma_d$ (corresponding to true eigenvectors/eigenvalues) and a continuous part $\sigma_c$ (corresponding to generalized/non-normalizable eigenvectors/eigenvalues). In that case, we would have

$$\psi(x) = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma_d} a_\lambda \varphi_\lambda(x) + \int_{\lambda \in \sigma_c}\mathrm d\lambda \  A(\lambda) \phi_\lambda(x)$$

$$\Psi_t(x) =\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma_d} a_\lambda \varphi_\lambda(x)e^{-iE_\lambda t/\hbar}+ \int_{\lambda \in \sigma_c}\mathrm d\lambda \  A(\lambda) \phi_\lambda(x) e^{-i E_\lambda t/\hbar}$$